# How to Get String From Parse JSON without String Id in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How do I get a string from Parse JSON with data like below?

My Data JSON :

```
[ 
   [ 
      "John Gorman",
      "3344764667200003",
      "Student",
      "2018-08-09 08:21:30.807"
   ],
   [ 
      "Andy William",
      "3403032311690003",
      "Student",
      "2018-08-09 08:21:30.807"
   ],
   [ 
      "Thomas Endry",
      "3408932311690078",
      "Student",
      "2018-08-09 08:21:30.807"
   ],
   [ 
      "Robet Calm",
      "3403077711690890",
      "Student",
      "2018-08-09 08:21:30.807"
   ]
]
```

I use the code below, then to get the string what I have to do, I really don't understand, if there is help, I really need to thank you.

```java
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("");
    //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = c.getString("What should I write here");
        System.out.println(c.getString(""));
    }
```

I want to get the string from Parse JSON that I have

How do I get a string for listview, for example:

```
John Gorman
3344764667200003
Student

Andy William
3403032311690003
Student

Thomas Endry
3408932311690078
Student

Robet Calm
3403077711690890
Student
```

Comment: I think maybe you have a mistake in your JSON string. Curly braces (`{` and `}`) enclose a JSON object while square brackets (`[` and `]`) enclose an array. In the string you posted you have an array where every element of that array is another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong with the posted code. See my comments inline:

> ```
> JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>                     the content of result is not an object, but an array!
>
> JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("");
>                                           ^^
>                                           a proper JSON document had better not have empty keys!
>
> //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>                         this was actually going in the right direction!
>
> for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
>     JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>                    the i-th element of the array is not an object, but an array!
> ```

Fixing the issues above:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONArray subArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < subArray.length(); j++) {
    System.out.println(subArray.getString(j));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful answer. Can you help me to place the string in the textview, for example like below:
````
TextName.setText();
TextId.setText();
TextClassLevel.setText();
````

Comment: @OnadHanif I think that belongs in a new question

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a JSONArray not object so use the below code.

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
   JSONArray array=jsonarray.getJSONArray(i);
     for(int j=0;j<array.length();j++){
     Log.d(TAG,array.getString(j));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("");
    //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = c.getString(0);
        String id = c.getString(1);
        String student = c.getString(2);
        // and so on ... This index refers to the index number on the string inside json object
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Hope this answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

Following method will construct a list of string from the given Json. You can pass that list in the adapter of the list view.

```
public List<String> getList (String result) throws JSONException {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray arr = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length(); j++) {
                sb.append(arr.getString(j));
                if(j<arr.length()-1) sb.append("\n");
            }
            list.add(sb.toString());
        }
        return list;
}
```